# Multiple CKEditors with different height

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to have 10 CKEditors in a page, all with the same customized configurations, but 9 of them with height 100, and one with size 250. This is how I initialize the CKEditors now:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 9; i++)
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor' + i, {
        customConfig : 'my_configs/small_box.js'
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('editor0', {
        customConfig : 'my_configs/small_box.js'
        height: 250
    });
```

With this code all I see are text boxes, not the CKEditor instances.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors? When do you try to initialize the CKEditors instances? Maybe it's before textareas are available in the DOM?

Comment: Is this the actual code? You are missing comma before `height`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because solutions involving typos are not likely to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution posted on behalf of the OP:

The code was missing a comma.